# Finding the transformation matrix that maps one 2d plane in 3d space to another 2d plane in 3d space

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have two 2d planes in 3d space $P_{1}$ and $P_{2}$ that are defined by $P_{1}: A_{1}x + B_{1}y + C_{1}z + D_{1} = 0$ and $P_{2}: A_{2}x + B_{2}y + C_{2}z + D_{2} = 0$. I would like to find a $4 \times 4$ transformation matrix $M$ that maps $P_{1}$ to $P_{2}$ such that $P_{2} = MP_{1}$.

Using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685495/transforming-a-3d-plane-using-a-4x4-matrix), I know that I can find the transformed plane given the matrix $M$ and original plane $P_1$, but I would instead like to find a matrix $M$ given the original plane $P_1$ and the new plane $P_2$. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945583/transform-plane-to-xy-plane) seems closer but it's for a specific transform to the x-y plane.

Comment: One correction to make to your question: replace "the" with "a". There will be infinitely many matrices carrying $P_1$ onto $P_2$. Perhaps the reason you are having trouble yourself is a mistaken idea that all elements of $M$ must be solved for. In truth, you are going to have to make some arbitrary choices. Also $P_1$ and $P_2$ are not "3d" planes. They are ordinary two-dimensional planes - though not necessarily passing through the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify $P_1$ and $P_2$ with the quaternions $$P_1 = -D_1 + A_1i + B_1j + C_1k\\P_2 = -D_2 + A_2i + B_2j + C_2k$$ respectively.

Now a quaternion $a+bi+cj+dk$ has a "scalar" part, which is just the $a$, and a "vector" part, which is $bi + cj + dk$, and which we identify with the 3-dimensional vector $(b,c,d)$ (in fact, quaternions came first, and our current terminology about "vectors" comes from the labeling of the non-real part of the quaternion as the "vector" part). Write the quaternion as $a + \vec v$, where $\vec v = bi + cj + dk$. So the quaternion is expressed as $a + \vec v$. Addition of quaternions is just $$(a + \vec v) + (u + \vec w) = (a +u) + (\vec v + \vec w)$$ and multiplication is $$(a + \vec v)(u + \vec w) = (au - \vec v \cdot \vec w) + (a\vec w + b\vec v + \vec v \times \vec w)$$
where $\vec v \cdot \vec w$ and $\vec v \times \vec w$ are just the ordinary dot product and cross product of 3-dimensional vectors and $a\vec w$ and $b\vec v$ are just ordinary scalar multiplications of vectors.

Now a quaternion $q = a + \vec v$ has a conjugate $\bar q = a - \vec v$. If you multiply them together you get
$$q\bar q = \bar q q = (a^2 + \vec v\cdot \vec v) + (-a\vec v + a\vec v - \vec v\times \vec v) = a^2 + \vec v\cdot\vec v$$
a real number. In particular, if $\vec v = bi+cj+dk$, then $q\bar q = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$. This allows us to compute the inverse of any quaternion:
$$\frac1q = \frac{\bar q}{\bar qq} = \frac aN - \frac bNi - \frac cNj-\frac dN k$$ where $N = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$

In particular, if we define $\vec V_1 =  A_1i + B_1j + C_1k$ and similarly for $\vec V_2$, we have $P_1 = -D_1 + \vec V_1, P_2 = -D_2 + \vec V_2$, and we can define
$$\begin{align}M = P_2\frac 1{P_1} &= (-D_2 +\vec V_2)(-D_1 -\vec V_1)\frac 1{N}\\
&= (D_1D_2 + \vec V_2\cdot \vec V_1)\frac 1N + (D_2\vec V_1 - D_1\vec V_2 - \vec V_2\times \vec V_1)\frac 1N\end{align}$$
where $N = A_1^2+B_1^2+C_1^2+D_1^2$.

If we treat quaternions as 4-vectors, left-multiplication of the quaternion by $M$ is a linear operation resulting in a new 4-vector. This means $M$ can be expressed as a $4\times 4$ matrix. For brevity, let me define
$$\begin{align}m_0 &= (A_1A2 + B_1B_2 + C_1C_2 + D_1D_2)/N\\
m_i &= (D_2A_1 - D_1A_2 + B_1C_2 - B_2C_1)/N\\
m_j &= (D_2B_1 - D_1B_2 + C_1A_2 - C_2A_1)/N\\
m_k &= (D_2C_1 - D_1C_2 + A_1B_2 - A_2B_1)/N\end{align}$$
so $M=m_0 + m_ii + m_jj + m_kk$. Then as a matrix,

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}m_0&-m_i&-m_j&-m_k\\
m_i&m_0&-m_k&m_j\\
m_j&m_k&m_0&-m_i\\
m_k&-m_j&m_i&m_0\end{bmatrix}$$

So where is that indeterminancy I talked about in the comment? This is because I made two decisions: First, not every $4\times 4$ transformation $M$ is representable by quaternion multiplication. In particular, note that the matrix for $M$ is skew-symmetric: $M^T$ changes differs from $M$ only by changing the signs of all off-diagonal elements. Further, the diagonal is constant, and in the off-diagonal elements every value appears twice. These are significant restrictions. Yet I decided to find an $M$ which is representable as a quaternion. Second, even with $M$ as a quaternion, the condition that $M$ carry the *plane* of $P_1$ to the *plane* of $P_2$ only requires that the scalar part of $MP_1(1 + \vec r)$ be $0$ for exactly the same vectors $\vec r$ as $P_2(1+\vec r)$ is. This is a much looser condition than $MP_1 = P_2$, which is what I used to define $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather straight forward way to find a $4 \times 4$ matrix $M$.

First, find the intersection line between the two planes.  The direction of this line is given by

$V = (A_1, B_1, C_1) \times (A_2, B_2, C_2) $

We're going to need a point on this line.  So set $z = 0$ and solve the remaining $2 \times 2$ system which is as follows

$ A_1 x + B_1 y + D_1 = 0 $

$ A_2 x + B_2 y + D_2 = 0 $

The solution, using Cramer's rule, is:

$ x_0 = \dfrac{ -D_1 B_2 + D_2 B_1 }{A_1 B_2 - A_2 B_1 } $

$ y_0 = \dfrac{ - A_1 D_2 + A_2 D_1 }{A_1 B_2 - A_2 B_1 } $

So the point on the intersection line is $P_0 = (x_0, y_0 , 0) $

Now, we are going to rotate points on the first plane, whose unit normal vector is,

$n_1 = \dfrac{(A_1, B_1, C_1)}{\sqrt{A_1^2+B_1^2+C_1^2}}$

And we rotate the points on this first plane, such that $n_1$ is sent to $n_2$ where

$n_2 = \dfrac{(A_2, B_2, C_2)}{\sqrt{A_2^2 + B_2^2 + C_2^2}} $

This rotation is not unique, however, if we select the rotation with the smallest angle possible, then the rotation is uniquely determined, and its axis of rotation will be

$ a = \dfrac{n_1 \times n_2 }{\| n_1 \times n_2 \| } $

And the angle of rotation $\theta$ is the angle between $n_1 $ and $n_2 $.

The axis of rotation whose direction is defined above, must pass through point $P_0$.

Now, the rotation matrix $R(\theta)$ is given by the Rodrigues' Rotation Matrix Formula, which is given by (other forms are equivalent):

$ R(\theta) = {a a}^T + (I - {a a}^T) \cos \theta + S_a \sin \theta $

where

$ S_a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - a_z && a_y \\ a_z && 0 && -a_x \\ - a_y && a_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

We have the unit vector $a$, and we have $\theta$, so $R(\theta)$ can be computed directly.

Now, the image of rotation of a point $r$ on the first plane is

$ r' = P_0 + R( r - P_0)  = R r + (I - R) P_0 $

Therefore, the required matrix $M$ takes the form,

$ M = \begin{bmatrix} R && (I - R) P_0 \\ 0^T && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Answer (score 0):

Here's is another simple solution that has the advantage that it does not require the evaluation of the Rodrigues' Rotation Matrix Formula, and does not require finding the intersection of the two planes.

If $r_1 = [x_1, y_1, z_1]^T $ is any point on the first plane, then

$ n_1^T (r_1 - r_{01}) = 0 $

where $r_{01}$ is a fixed point on the first plane.  And we can assume without any loss of generality that $n_1$ is a unit vector.

Similarly for the second plane, we have

$ n_2^T (r_2 - r_{02}) = 0 $

where $n_2$ is also a unit vector.

This method requires that we take any unit vector $u_1$ that is perpendicular to $n_1$ and compute the vector $u_2 = n_1 \times u_1 $.  The triple $u_1, u_2, n_1$ defines a coordinate reference frame, i.e.

$[u_1, u_2, n_1] = R_1 $

from the definition of $u_1, u_2$ it follows that $R_1$ is a rotation matrix.

Similarly, find any unit vector $v_1$ that is perpendicular to $n_2$ and define $v_2 = n_2 \times v_1 $, then we will have

$[v_1, v_2, n_2] = R_2 $

where $R_2$ is a rotation matrix.

If $p_1$ and $p_2$ are arbitrary vectors that have their $z$ component equal to zero, then we can write

$r_1 = r_{01} + R_1 p_1 $

and

$r_2 = r_{02} + R_2 p_2 $

To do the mapping, we'll take $p_1 = p_2$, and we'll apply the following affine transformation to $r_1$

$ f(r_1) = R^* (r_1 - r_{01} ) + r_{02} \hspace{10pt}(1) $

Substituting the above equations, we get

$ f(r_1) = R^* ( R_1 p_1 ) + r_{02} $

we want $f(r_1) = r_2$, thus we must take our $R^* = R_2 R_1^{-1} = R_2 R_1^T $

If we do that, then $f(r_1) = r_2$, and we're done.

Equation $(1)$ can re-written as

$ f(r_1) = R^* r_1 + \bigg(r_{02} - R^* r_{01}\bigg) $

It follows that the matrix $4 \times 4$ transformation matrix $M$ applied to the homogeneous coordinate vector $[x, y, z, 1]^T $ is

$ M = \begin{bmatrix} R^*  && r_{02} - R^* r_{01} \\ 0 ^T && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Answer (score 0):

Here's a third solution that depends on the availability of a linear system solver and Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

We're given the first plane as $n_1^T r = 0$ and the second plane as $n_2^T r= 0$, where $n_1, n_2$ are $4 \times 1$ vectors, and $r= [x, y, z, 1]^T $ is also a $4 \times 1$ vector.  I will assume that $n_1$ and $n_2$ have already been normalized to have unity length.

Now we want to rotate $n_1$ into $n_2$.  When rotating in $\mathbb{R}^4$, rotation is made in a plane that contains the vector difference $(n_1 - n_2) $ and another vector that is orthogonal to $(n_1 - n_2)$.

Therefore, the first step is to generate the orthogonal complement of $(n_1 - n_2)$, and this can done by solving the $1 \times 4$ system:

$ (n_1 - n_2)^T u = 0 $

This system has only one equation in $4$ variables.  The solution is the 3-dimensional subspace

$U = \{ u \ | \ u = c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2 + c_3 u_3 \} $

Choose arbitrary values for $c_1, c_2, c_3$ (not all zero) and define

$v_1 = n_1 - n_2 $

$v_2 = c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2 + c_3 u_3 $

as the spanning vectors of the plane in which rotation will occur.  Note that $v_2$ is orthogonal to $v_1$

Next, generate the orthogonal complement of $\{v_1, v_2 \}$, by solving

$v_1^T r = 0 $

$v_2^T r = 0 $

A system of two equations in $4$ unknowns.

Let the solution space be spanned by the two linearly independent vectors $v_3, v_4$.

Now we want to orthogonalize/normalize the set $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \} $

And this can be done by Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.  The output of the orthogonalization will be matrix $W$:

$W = [w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4] $

Rotation of $n_1$ into $n_2$ is on the plane spanned by $w_1$ and $w_2$.

Now, find the coordinates of $n_1$ and $n_2$ with respect to the basis $W$.  These are:

$n_1' = W^T n_1 $

$n_2' = W^T n_2 $

The first two components of $n_1'$ and $n_2'$ will determine the rotation angle.  This is because, just as in normal $2D$ rotation, we have,

$ n'_{2x} = \cos(\theta) n'_{1x} - \sin(\theta) n'_{1y} $

$ n'_{2y} = \sin(\theta) n'_{1x} + \cos(\theta) n'_{1y} $

This equation can be solved for $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta) $ as follows:

$ \cos(\theta) = \dfrac{ n'_{2x} n'_{1x} + n'_{2y} n'_{1y} }{{n'_{1x}}^2 + {n'_{1y}}^2 } $

$ \sin(\theta) = \dfrac{ n'_{1x} n'_{2y} - n'_{1y} n'_{2x} } { {n'_{1x}}^2 + {n'_{1y}}^2 } $

In the basis $\{ w_1 , w_2 , w_3, w_4 \}$, the rotation matrix is

$ R_W = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) && - \sin(\theta) && 0 && 0 \\ \sin(\theta && \cos(\theta) && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore the rotatation matrix in the standard basis will be

$R = W R_W W^T $

And this is our matrix $M$, so

$ M = W R_W W^T $

We now have $M n_1  = n_2 $.

Note that since $M$ is a rotation matrix (unitary), then $M^T M  = I$.

Further, if $r = [x, y, z, 1]$ and $n_1^T r = 0 $, then

$0 = n_1^T r = n_1^T M^T M r = (M n_1)^T M r = n_2^T M r $

Hence if $r$ is on the first plane (i.e. $n_1^T r = 0 $) then $ M r $ is on the second plane (i.e. $n_2^T M r = 0 $).

This means that the transformation we need to apply to a point on the first plane, $r = [x, y, z, 1] $ is pre-multiply it by the linear transformation matrix $M$ and this will send it to another point which is on the second plane.